# NSInternalInconsistencyException using popViewControllerAnimated:NO

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

When running my program, I receive the following crash error:

Assertion failure in -[UISearchDisplayController setActive:animated:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.23/UISearchDisplayController.m:1275

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'search contents navigation controller must not change between -setActive:YES and -setActive:NO'

The error occurs when I hit cancel on a search bar, after the following block of code:

```
-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *) searchBar {
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    _displayRowData = nil;
    [_sdc.searchResultsTableView reloadData];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Note: this error goes away when I switch to:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This error persists even when I comment out the only call I have to -setActive.

What is the proper way to popViewController without animation? There is another view controller on the navigation stack when this is called. I cannot use dismissViewController because I need to keep everything on the navigation stack. I just want a clean transition to my previous view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED. Calling the following before popping fixed my problem:

```
[_sdc setActive:NO animated:YES];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```